# Is there any way to import data from relational database to Accumulo?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, accumulo

I am new in Accumulo and currently trying to migrate all of data from relational database such as PostgreSQL and Oracle to Accumulo. How do I do this? Is there a direct API that I can use or do I need to use third program?

Can anyone tell me is there any import option available for Accumulo to import the file and create the tables?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API in Accumulo to do this, but some users may have written something to help. Using Accumulo requires you to think about how you want to query your data, so you should probably do the migration carefully. Please consider contacting Accumulo's [user mailing list](https://accumulo.apache.org/contact-us) to discuss possible solutions with other users who may have insight into doing this.

Answer (score -1):

While there is no direct way to migrate from Accumulo; you can try using the following methods:

1. Export to Intermediate Format: You can export your data from the relational database to an intermediate format like CSV, Avro, or Parquet. Once exported, you can use Accumulo's provided APIs or tools to ingest the data into Accumulo. Accumulo provides a Java API that allows you to programmatically insert data into Accumulo, or you can use tools like Apache NiFi to automate the ingestion process.
2. Apache Sqoop: It supports importing data from various relational databases, including PostgreSQL and Oracle, into Accumulo. Sqoop can be used to extract data from your source database and load it directly into Accumulo.
3. Custom Scripts: You can write custom scripts using your preferred programming language to extract data from your relational database and insert it into Accumulo. You would need to establish connections to both databases and perform the necessary transformations to convert the data into the appropriate format for Accumulo.